# How to solve MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am getting the following exception while getting a message from MQ local queue.this is my code for connection.after running the code  i am getting following exception

```
 MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
    MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
    Closure reason = 2009
    MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
    MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
    Closure reason = 2009
    com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: 
                                     Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
    MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
    Closure reason = 2009
```

Here is my  code

```
  public class Demo {
            private MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
            public int port = 1422;
            public String hostname = "192.168.1.5";//IP OF HOST
            public String channel = "QM_ORANGE.QM_APPLE";//channel name
            public String qManager = "QM_ORANGE";//queue manager name
            public String inputQName = "Q1";//remote q type
            public String outputQName = "QM_APPLE";//queue manager

            public Demo() {
                super();
            }

            private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                // Set up MQ environment
                MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
                MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
                MQEnvironment.port = port;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                Demo readQ = new Demo();

                try {
                    readQ.init(args);
                    readQ.selectQMgr();
                    readQ.read();
                    readQ.write();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Usage: java MQRead <-h host> <-p port> <-c channel> <-m QueueManagerName> <-q QueueName>");
                    System.exit(1);
                } catch (MQException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            private void read() throws MQException {
                int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                        + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;

                MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue(inputQName, openOptions,
                        null, // default q manager
                        null, // no dynamic q name
                        null); // no alternate user id

                System.out.println("MQRead v1.0 connected.\n");

                int depth = queue.getCurrentDepth();
                System.out.println("Current depth: " + depth + "\n");
                if (depth == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                        + MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT;
                while (true) {
                    MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
                    try {
                        queue.get(message, getOptions);
                        byte[] b = new byte[message.getMessageLength()];
                        message.readFully(b);
                        System.out.println(new String(b));
                        message.clearMessage();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("IOException during GET: " + e.getMessage());
                        break;
                    } catch (MQException e) {
                        if (e.completionCode == 2
                                && e.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
                            if (depth > 0) {
                                System.out.println("All messages read.");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("GET Exception: "+e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                queue.close();
                _queueManager.disconnect();
            }

            private void selectQMgr() throws MQException {
                _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
            }

            private void write() throws MQException {
                int lineNum = 0;
                int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                try {
                    MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions,
                            null, // default q manager
                            null, // no dynamic q name
                            null); // no alternate user id

                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

                    System.out.println("MQWrite v1.0 connected");
                    System.out.println("and ready for input, terminate with ^Z\n\n");

                    // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text in UTF format..
                    MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
                    sendmsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                    sendmsg.feedback = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
                    sendmsg.messageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
                    sendmsg.replyToQueueName = "ROGER.QUEUE";
                    sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = qManager;

                    MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the
                                                                            // defaults,
                                                                            // same
                    // as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant

                    String line = "test message";
                    sendmsg.clearMessage();
                    sendmsg.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
                    sendmsg.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
                    sendmsg.writeString(line);

                    // put the message on the queue

                    queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
                    System.out.println(++lineNum + ": " + line);

                    queue.close();
                    _queueManager.disconnect();

                } catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex) {
                    System.out.println(mqex);
                } catch (java.io.IOException ioex) {
                    System.out.println("An MQ IO error occurred : " + ioex);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21226703) for potential reasons?

Comment: What kind of channel are you trying to connect to? The name suggest a sender or receiver channel. You need to connect to a server connection channel.

Comment: its the server connection channel

Comment: Have a look in AMQERR01.LOG, but I agree with the previous comment - the channel name looks like a SDR (based on the queue manager name) not a SVRCONN. If it is really is a SVRCONN then it's not good practice to name it like a SDR/RVCR pair :)

Answer (score 1):

The commentors are correct that based on the naming that looks like an MCA channel and not an MQI channel.  However, when I test a client connection to a RCVR channel I get back `2539=MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR`.

On the other hand, there are many causes for a 2009 when using clients connecting to MQI channels.  Almost all of them show up in the QMgr's error logs so if the question is "How to solve 2009?" the answer is "By  recreating the error and immediately looking in the QMgr's `AMQERR01.LOG` file."

Some possibilities include...

- Closed by an exit.
- Closed by CONNAUTH.
- QMgr resource error.
- Channel has been configuration-locked.

Many MQ development issues can only be resolved by looking at the diagnostic messages produced at the queue manager.  Among other reasons, limiting the information that can leak to an attacker is part of the security design.  It's OK for the MQ Admin to know the details but the attacker is supposed to get back a rather vague result.  In a legitimate app development environment the developers are expected to have access to the QMgr diagnostics that an attacker would not.  So go get the error log.

If for some reason you are unable to convince the MQ Admins to provide the log data or it is otherwise inaccessible, you can set up your own fully functional, fully licensed, free MQ server on your desktop.  Information on how to download MQ Advanced for Developers is available from the [ibm-mq](/questions/tagged/ibm-mq) tag wiki.  (Hover over the tag and click 'info' from the fly-out dialog to go there.)

You can also watch [*No-Cost, Fully Licensed IBM MQ Sandbox*](https://youtu.be/xX6hSGVZ8ds) which is a video tutorial explaining how to create a dedicated Red Hat virtual machine with MQ Advanced for Developers, using all free and fully licensed software, including where to go to obtain the virtualization software and Red Hat OS.

Once you have that set up, create a QMgr configured like your Integration Test QMgr recreate the error and check the logs.  If you connect OK and can't recreate the error at least you can go back to the MQ Admins knowing it's not your code that's the problem.